# Is there any reason to use scanf or fscanf over fgets+sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

Since you're not reading from the stream it seems much more flexible.
Both to mention that since you can easily change the timing/code location of the reads then you can with a c stream(am I wrong, can you make strings, ect into c `FILE *` streams)?

Plus, I don't know I just feel a bit odd about `scanf`. Any pros/cons to `scanf` would be appreciated.

Edit: I meant the use of scanf or fscanf vs the combo of  fgets+sscanf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well addressed in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

> Why does everyone say not to use
>   scanf? What should I use instead?

If you are reading from a trusted file (NOT `stdin`), there's no point in using `fgets + sscanf` instead of `fscanf`. Indeed using `scanf` (reading from `stdin`) is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

If you were expecting an `integer` but you read a  `floating point` or some other incompatible type, you can check the return value of `scanf`. If it returns zero, then you didn't read an `integer` - but with `fgets` you can't do that. Also, by checking the return value of `scanf` you can see the number of items read.

Comment: you can do that with sscanf though.

Comment: You could also try trying reading other different types/simpe patterns out the string as many times as you wish on error. I don't think there is a simple way to do that with scanf.

Comment: Edit: I meant the use scanf or fscanf vs the combo of fgets+sscanf