Is it possible for a single scanf command to take either one or two inputs?
printf("Commands:\n");
printf("  add <word>:              adds a new word to dictionary\n");
printf("  lookup <word>:           searches for a word\n");
printf("  print:                   shows all words currently in the dictionary\n");
printf("  load <file_name>:        reads in dictionary from a file\n");
printf("  save <file_name>:        writes dictionary to a file\n");
printf("  check <file_name>: spell checks the specified file\n");
printf("  exit:                    exits the program\n");

while (t == 1) {
    char command[MAX_CMD_LEN];
    char word[MAX_CMD_LEN];
    printf("spell_check> ");
    int inputs = scanf("%s " " %s", command, word);

In the code above, is there a way for scanf to differentiate if my command requires two inputs (ex: add word) or if it requires only one (ex: exit) in the same scanf prompt? As written, scanf still requires a second input if I do a command such as exit.

This is unlikely that scanf will be appropriate -- when you know what to expect. More a parsing problem.

Forget scanf. Use fgets. Problem solved.

And then use sscanf ("%s", command) to pick the command from the line read with fgets() and decide what to do based on a comparison of command to your list. (can be automated with a lookup table that provides a function pointer to call based on the command) Or just if (strcmp (command, "add") == 0) {// do add} else if (strcmp (command, "lookup") == 0) {// do lookup) ... Also note -- you only need ONE printf() to output your entire menu. That's what '\n' is for. You can leave the text as separate lines and the compiler will concatenate adjacent string-literals during compilation.

You could use int inputs = scanf(”%10s %10[^\n ]”, command, word); and then check the value in inputs, which might be 2, 1, 0, or EOF.  Actually, zero probably isn't possible, but…  Adjust the sizes to match your variable sizes.  It's still probably better to read a line and then parse it, possibly with sscanf().

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6395950/10622916 which refers to https://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

@JonathanLeffler, I don't think that's what asker wants, because the   will match any number of newlines before the %[ starts to match.

@TobySpeight: Ugh!  Yes, you're right.  Reading a line and parsing it with sscanf() would work — it's usually the better way to go if you must (want to) stick with the scanf family of functions.  If you don't mind not using the scanf() family of functions, reading a line and parsing it afterwards is still the right way to go.

scanf is intended to read a bunch of data without caring for any white space or new line characters: they are only used as separators. If you want you input to be line oriented, you must first use fgets to get a line of input, and then parse that line with sscanf if the input is simple enough.
Here you could do:
...
while (t == 1) {
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];   // after e.g. #define MAX_LINE_LEN MAX_CMD_LEN*2+4
    char command[MAX_CMD_LEN];
    char word[MAX_CMD_LEN];
    printf("spell_check> ");
    if (NULL == fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        // handle read error
        ...
    }
    if (strcspn(line, "\n") == sizeof(line) -1) {
        // handle line too long
        ...
    }
    int inputs = sscanf(line, "%s%s", command, word);
    // inputs means 0:empty line, 1:one single command, 2:command AND word



Is it possible for a single scanf command to take either one or two inputs?

Not well.
OP's input or command has an implied format: characters followed by a line-feed.
scanf("%s", ... is weak as it first consumes 0 or more leading white-spaces (which could include multiple '\n') and then reads an unlimited number of non-white-spaces characters risking buffer overflow.
Code could use char buf[100]; scanf("%99[^\n]%*1[\n]", buf) to read the command (without the '\n') into buf[] and then later parse for 1 or 2  or ... tokens.
More commonly code uses char buf[100]; fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); to read the command (and a potential '\n') into buf[] and then later parse into tokens.
Really good input handling also is well behaved when the line of user input is longer than expected, ends with an end-of-file signal (and not a '\n'), is only "\n", etc.
Good parsing parsing detects mal-formed text: too few tokens, too many tokens, invalid tokens, ...
Best advice: separate reading a line of input from parsing the token and use lots of error detection.
Read a line
while (t == 1) {
  //                          command     space   word      \0 
  #define COMMAND_LINE_SIZE (MAX_CMD_LEN + 1 + MAX_CMD_LEN + 1)
  char buf[COMMAND_LINE_SIZE * 2]; // Be generous, use twice expected max.
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    break;  // No more input.
  } 

and then parse
There are many ways to do this.  Following uses sscanf().
  #define STR(s) STR2(s)
  #define STR2(s) #s
  char command[MAX_CMD_LEN + 1];
  char word[MAX_CMD_LEN + 1];
  // Form a ["%" width "s"] per each token.
  #define COMMAND_FMT "%" STR(MAX_CMD_LEN) "s"
  #define WORD_FMT "%" STR(MAX_CMD_LEN) "s"

  printf("spell_check> ");
  char extra;
  int inputs = sscanf(buf, COMMAND_FMT WORD_FMT " %c", command, word, &extra);
  switch (inputs) {
    case 1: // Command only.
      break;
    case 2: // Command and word.
      break;
    default: // Too few or too many tokens.
  }        


This is a very common problem. A more robust and flexible way is to use a parser-generator, offloading much of the testing to the generator. For example, one could use fgets then pass the string to re2c generator.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int lex(const char *s) {
    const char *YYCURSOR = s, *YYMARKER, *yyt1, *yyt2;
    const char *s0, *s1;
    /*!re2c
    re2c:yyfill:enable = 0;
    re2c:define:YYCTYPE = char;

    ws = [ \f\r\t\v];
    nl = [\n];
    word = [A-Za-z0-9']+; // pretty restricted
    filename = [A-Za-z0-9_/.]+; // for starters... what about spaces?

    ws* 'add' ws+ @s0 word @s1 ws* nl
        { printf("add <%.*s>\n", (int)(s1 - s0), s0); return 1; }
    ws* 'lookup' ws+ @s0 word @s1 ws* nl
        { printf("lookup <%.*s>\n", (int)(s1 - s0), s0); return 1; }
    ws* 'print' ws* nl
        { printf("print\n"); return 1; }
    ws* 'load' ws+ @s0 filename @s1 ws* nl
        { printf("load <%.*s>\n", (int)(s1 - s0), s0); return 1; }
    //...
    * { return 0; }
    */
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Commands:\n");
    printf("  add <word>:              adds a new word to dictionary\n");
    /* ... */
    printf("  exit:                    exits the program\n");

    assert(!lex("add\n"));
    assert(lex("  Add   fds  \n"));
    assert(lex("lookup foo  \n"));
    assert(lex("  PRINt  \n"));
    assert(lex(" LoAd /arr.txt \n"));
    //assert(lex("  SAVE  foo/bar.txt  \n"));
    //assert(lex("  cHeck   check.txt  \n"));
    //assert(lex("  eXiT  \n"));
    return 0;
}

This may not be suitable because the programme undergoes a pre-complation step with re2c.
